# TypeScript: how to type guard union type

Tags: typescript

The function `compose` can have an object or an array of objects as its argument.
In `compose`, the type guard differentiates between the object and the array. The
function `mapper` can only handle objects and by using the type guard, only objects are fet to it.

```
interface Link {
   something: string;
}

function compose(link: Link|Link[]) {
  if (link instanceof Array) {
    R.map(function(l) {
      return mapper(l);
    }, link);
  } else {
      return mapper(link);
  }
}

function mapper(link: Link) {
  return link;
}
```

Compiling this example results in the error:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'Link | Link[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Link'

This error is understandable as mapper gets an union type as its argument but expects an single object only. This is not what I hoped for when using the type guard. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you do a tsc --version and report the version you are using?

Comment: message TS6029: Version 1.4.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems TypeScript 1.4.0.0 does not infer that `link` must be of type `Link` when it is not of type `Array`. A small change should solve that:

```
function compose(link: Link|Link[]) {
  if (link instanceof Array) {
    R.map(function(l) {
      return mapper(l);
    }, link);
  } else if (link instanceof Link) {
      return mapper(link);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could assert the type:

```
return mapper(<Link> link);
```

Comment: I find the alternative the most elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: Note that, in `.tsx`, you have to use `link as Link`.